Using swr_convert to resample audio frames resulted in audio with significant noise
I attempted to use swr_convert to resample audio frames from 44100 Hz to 16000 Hz, processing the frames one by one for testing purposes. However, the resulting audio appears to be mixed with noise.
The following code shows how I resample a single audio frame:

   AVFrame* output_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!output_frame) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate output AVFrame");
    }

    AVRational output_time_base = {1, output_sample_rate};
    
    SwrContext* swr_ctx = swr_alloc();
    if (!swr_ctx) {
        av_frame_free(&output_frame);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate SwrContext");
    }

    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "in_sample_fmt", aframe->format, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "out_sample_fmt", output_format, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "in_channel_layout", aframe->channel_layout, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "out_channel_layout", output_channel_layout, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "in_sample_rate", aframe->sample_rate, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "out_sample_rate", output_sample_rate, 0);

    if (swr_init(swr_ctx) < 0) {
        swr_free(&swr_ctx);
        av_frame_free(&output_frame);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize SwrContext");
    }

    output_frame->format = output_format;
    output_frame->channel_layout = output_channel_layout;
    output_frame->sample_rate = output_sample_rate;

    int64_t delay = swr_get_delay(swr_ctx, aframe->sample_rate);
    output_frame->nb_samples = av_rescale_rnd(
        delay + aframe->nb_samples, output_sample_rate, aframe->sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);
        
    output_frame->nb_samples = av_rescale_rnd(
        aframe->nb_samples, output_sample_rate, aframe->sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);

    if (av_frame_get_buffer(output_frame, 0) < 0) {
        swr_free(&swr_ctx);
        av_frame_free(&output_frame);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate buffer for output AVFrame");
    }

    int ret = swr_convert(swr_ctx,
                          output_frame->data, output_frame->nb_samples,
                          (const uint8_t**)aframe->data, aframe->nb_samples);

    if (ret < 0) {
        swr_free(&swr_ctx);
        av_frame_free(&output_frame);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to resample audio data");
    }

    if (aframe->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
        output_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(aframe->pts, {1, aframe->sample_rate}, output_time_base);
    } else {
        output_frame->pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
    }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
